# How to manipulate a PIR sensor?

Tags: infrared, electromagnetic, light-sensor, pir

The passive infrared (PIR) motion sensor detects movement of infrared light sources with wavelengths ranging from 7 μm to 14 μm. Is there a way to make it detect below 10μm or to make it detect between particular wavelengths?

I actually want to detect humans having a particular temperature.
Basically, any body with a particular temperature has a characteristic IR radiation of a fixed wavelength.
what I am trying to find is a way to detect humans having temperature above 100F, which technically relates to a wavelength below 10um approx.

So there are complex ways to do the same... But what I trying to achieve is to find a cost-effective way to use a commercially available PIR sensor and tweak it (using filters) to make it detect objects having the specified wavelength.

Wanted to know if what I thought could work or not?

Comment: What is your application? What wavelengths are you actually interested in? 7-10um? Shorter than 7um? Filters are very, very, expensive. (Hundreds to thousands of dollars per square inch)

Comment: If you want to restrict it to shorter wavelengths, replace the plastic lens/cover with a suitable IR glass one. Calcium fluoride or sapphire lenses for example are not too expensive but will block longer wavelength IR.

Comment: Yeah, I actually want to detect humans having a particular temperature.
Basically, any body with a particular temperature has a characteristic IR radiation of a fixed wavelength. 
what I am trying to find is a way to detect humans having temperature above 100F, which technically relates to a wavelength below 10um approx.

So there are complex ways to do the same... But what I trying to achieve is to find a cost-effective way to use a commercially available PIR sensor and tweak it (using filters) to make it detect objects having the specified wavelength.

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, the common PIR sensor does already detect below \$10\,\mu\text{m}\$...down to \$7\,\mu\text{m}\$. If you want to restrict the range of wavelengths you will need to add filters.

If your real goal is to detect at wavelengths much lower, the \$3\,\mu\text{m}\$ to \$5\,\mu\text{m}\$ band is popular for terrestrial applications, but you need a completely different detector. There are many to chose from.

Comment: Yeah, I actually want to detect humans having a particular temperature.
Basically, any body with a particular temperature has a characteristic IR radiation of a fixed wavelength. 
what I am trying to find is a way to detect humans having temperature above 100F, which technically relates to a wavelength below 10um approx.

So there complex ways to do the same... But what I trying to achieve is to find a cost-effective way to use commercially available PIR sensor and tweak it (using filters) to make it detect object having the specified wavelength.

Comment: I think you are confused about black-body radiation. An ideal black body will emit a **spectrum** of light with a **peak wavelength** that is determined by its temperature. If you only look at a single wavelength or a narrow band of wavelengths the amount of energy emitted will vary because of the temperature of the body but also because of the body's emissivity and reflected IR. Furthermore, the typical PIR sensor does nor respond to the intensity of IR but to **changes** in intensity.